# How to control process of reading file in directory?

Tags: php

I  need to write all files in directory. Each of files have size about 7 mb.

When I open file I must parse that, save and open next file.

I know that will appear issue with stack memory. How can I control this more optimize?

Comment: `issue with stack memory` What issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to close files after each file is read:

```
$myfile = fopen("webdictionary.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("webdictionary.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
// $myfile = // next file
// fclose($myfile)
....
```

Comment: If this is HTML file to parsing, how should I open this, that after use DOMDocument?

Comment: Try this: $doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents('file.html'));

Comment: But how to close file opened by `file_get_contents`?

Comment: When you use file_get_contents the file is automatically closed for you.